# Create list of specific files in subdirectories

Tags: php, html, directory-listing, file-listing

I have a structure:

- [catalogues]
- [catalogue-name-1]

  - [data_html]

    - *name-1.html* - table of posted values from another form
    - *name-2.html* - table of posted values from another form
    - *name-3.html* - table of posted values from another form
    - ...
    - *name-n.html* - table of posted values from another form
  - *catalogue-name-1.html*
  - [catalogue-name-2]

    - *catalogue-name-2.html*
  - [catalogue-name-3]

    - *catalogue-name-3.html*

*index.php*

1. How shall I write the function in *catalogue-name-?.html* to have merged the content of all *data_html*-tables in one html-table in *catalogue-name-?.html*?
2. How shall I write the *index.php* to have listed all *catalogue-name-?.html* files as a list of links?

   - <a href="catalogue-name-1.html">name-1</a>
   - <a href="catalogue-name-2.html">name-2</a>
   - <a href="catalogue-name-3.html">name-3</a>
   - ...
   - <a href="catalogue-name-n.html">name-n</a>

Comment: Try `/catalogues/catalogue-name-1/catalogue-name-1.html` and so on (if the folder `catalogue` is in the document root)

Comment: Why did you revert the edit that made the question more readable? The more readable the question is, the more likely you are to get answers.

Comment: It would also help if you posted the code you already have, explaining what does/doesn't work and where you are stuck. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you are expected to try to write the code yourself first. [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) might help getting the files

Comment: Thank you for the hints. There are 3 PHP files involved:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hints. There are 3 PHP files involved:
*index.php* - there is an entry form posting values into the *work/data.php* file, then values manipulated in it are saved in new HTML files in respective *data_htm*l folders to be then shown by *work/preview.php*. In *data.php*, there is about this code:

```
<?php
// directory names 
$dir_catalogues = '../catalogues/';
$dir_catalogue = $dir_catalogues.$_POST['catalogue_name'];
$dir_html = $dir_catalogue.'/data_html/'; 
$dir_csv = $dir_catalogue.'/data_csv/';

//Check if the directory with the name already exists
//Create our directory if it does not exist
if (!is_dir($dir_catalogues)) {
mkdir($dir_catalogues);
echo "Directory ".$dir_catalogues." created<br>";
}
if (!is_dir($dir_catalogue)) {
mkdir($dir_catalogue);
echo "Directory ".$dir_catalogue." created<br>";
}
if (!is_dir($dir_html)) {
mkdir($dir_html);
echo "Directory ".$dir_html." created<br>";
}
if (!is_dir($dir_csv)) {
mkdir($dir_csv);
echo "Directory ".$dir_csv." created";
}

// file names 
$img_name_html = $_POST['img_name'].'.html';
$img_name_csv = $_POST['img_name'].'.csv';
$catalogue_name = 'catalogue-'.$_POST['catalogue_name'].'.html';

// HTML file content 
$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Images rights information</title>
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<table cellpadding="5">
<th colspan="2">Image info</th>
<tr class="thumb_row""><td class="logo" colspan="2"><img class="img_thumb" src="'.$_POST['img_use_url'].'" alt="Thumbnail"><h3>'.$_POST['img_title'].'</h3></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">File name</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Description</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_description'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Source URL</td><td colspan="5"><a href="'.$_POST['img_source_url'].'" target="_blank">'.$_POST['img_source_url'].'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Image use URL</td><td colspan="5"><a href="'.$_POST['img_use_url'].'" target="_blank">'.$_POST['img_use_url'].'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Copyright owner</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_copyright_owner'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Author</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_author'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Author\'s URL</td><td colspan="5"><a href="'.$_POST['img_author_url'].'" target="_blank">'.$_POST['img_author_url'].'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">License</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_license'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">License Nr.</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_license_nr'].'</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>';
......
// create catalogue HTML file
    file_put_contents($dir_catalogue .'/'.$catalogue_name, $html, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made have achieved some progress (found and applied som working scripts). But I stuck at the following:
sofar I have in my code about this:

```html
<!-- FILE HEADDINGS -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Images rights information</title>
 <style>
  *{font-family: arial, tahoma, verdana;}
  .wrapper{width: 900px; margin:auto;box-sizing:border-box;}
  table{width:100%}
  th{font-size:2.2em; font-weight:bold;}
  .thumb_row{background:#eee;}
  td.logo, th{border-bottom:2px solid #999;}
  .img_thumb{max_height: 180px; width:auto; margin: .2em; float:left;}
  td.logo img{ float: left; margin-right:2em;}
  td a img{border: 2px solid blue;}
  td a:hover img{border: 2px solid orange;}
  td.lab{font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top;}
  td h3{font-size:2em; font-weight:bold}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- FILE HEADDINGS END -->
<table cellpadding="5">
<th colspan="2">Image info</th>
<tr class="thumb_row"><td class="logo" colspan="2"><img class="img_thumb" src="'.$_POST['img_use_url'].'" alt="Thumbnail"><h3>'.$_POST['img_title'].'</h3></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">File name</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_name'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Description</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_description'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Source URL</td><td colspan="5"><a href="'.$_POST['img_source_url'].'" target="_blank">'.$_POST['img_source_url'].'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Image use URL</td><td colspan="5"><a href="'.$_POST['img_use_url'].'" target="_blank">'.$_POST['img_use_url'].'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Copyright owner</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_copyright_owner'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Author</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_author'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">Author\'s URL</td><td colspan="5"><a href="'.$_POST['img_author_url'].'" target="_blank">'.$_POST['img_author_url'].'</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">License</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_license'].'</td></tr>
<tr><td width="140" class="lab">License Nr.</td><td colspan="5">'.$_POST['img_license_nr'].'</td></tr>
</table>
<!-- FILE FOOTER -->
</div>
</body>
</html>

// CSV file content

$csv = $_POST['catalogue_name'].'|'.$_POST['img_title'].'|'.$_POST['img_name'].'|'.$_POST['img_description'].'|'.$_POST['img_source_url'].'|'.$_POST['img_copyright_owner'].'|'.$_POST['img_author'].'|'.$_POST['img_author_url'].'|'.$_POST['img_license'].'|'.$_POST['img_license_nr'];

// create catalogue HTML file
 file_put_contents($dir_catalogue .'/'.$catalogue_name.'.html', $html, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
 file_put_contents($dir_catalogue .'/index.html', $html, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
// create catalogue CSV file
 file_put_contents($dir_catalogue .'/'.$catalogue_name.'.csv', $csv, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
 file_put_contents($dir_catalogue .'/index.csv', $csv, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

But the result is that the entire $html code is inserted into the catalog file (I want to have the "headings" added only in the beginning, the all individually saved tables, and the "footer" also always only on end of the HTML-catalog file.
The CSV output has all variables put into one endless line. I want to have each record in one line.